# display just blinks after installing Lubuntu

Tags: installation

I want to learn about Ubuntu by installing it on an old laptop.  It's an AMD sempron 3000, 792Mhz 448 MB ram.  I burned the default iso and booted up.  It chugs along for a couple minutes, then I just see the screen blinking showing a mouse pointer for a milisec, then blinks away, then back...

I looked for answers and found suggestions to try Lubuntu and the alternate install.  I tried that, and it did walk through all the text menu steps to install.  Now when I boot I get a grub menu and when I select Ubuntu, all I get it that same blinking screen with a brief flash of a graphic pointer every couple seconds.

I looked for answers again and I found something about boot parameters to help the video, but I don't know what to do.  My video is SiS M760GX.  Any ideas?

Comment: As of [this page](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/SiS) your chip is supported with the default xorg driver. There is a note that reducing the bit depth to 16bit can help if the screen flickers.

Answer (score 0):

Your system is fairly old (some would call it ancient). Your RAM is also too low. Try installing a lighter version of Ubuntu, like Lubuntu.